# TRY_TO_DATE with pattern?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has a TO_DATE(string, pattern) function, but currently has no TRY_TO_DATE version of the function with the same signature. While we've built a javascript parsing function as a workaround, it has abysmal performance due to its complexity and the fact that it's performance could never measure against a real native function.

Is there a roadmap for the availability of such native function? Is there a community voting board to prioritize such function?

Comment: Other databases, such as SQL Server, do have functions which can try to parse a date.  However, keep in mind the best solution here might be to standardize your date data in a correct format.

Comment: The problem is that we do not have any control over the inputs we received; Overall, we have a couple thousands of files to import. Some are from internal system of which we can ask nicely the team maintaining the system, while the rest are external third party, legacy mainframe stuff that is immutable (too expensive to have a custom extract for our need), etc. So We have no choice but to deal with those dates locally. And again, Snowflake does have a to_date(string, pattern) function, as well as a try_to_date(string). I'm complaining about the lack of a try_to_date(string, pattern) function.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is not a parameter for this function, you can set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT to force a pattern for TRY_TO_DATE function:

```
ALTER SESSION SET DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('2020-04-05'); -- will return a date value

ALTER SESSION SET DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
SELECT TRY_TO_DATE('2020-04-05'); -- will return NULL
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#date-input-format

You can use Snowflake Ideas to suggest and vote for new features:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Comment: Allow me to put things into context: We import our file into a staging zone and everything there is cast as string. We then move thing to a more business-friendly layer where we perform proper typing. The suggested approach would limit us to a single date format per table, which is a limit that is muhc too low for a lot of our files.

Answer (score 0):

[Release Notes - August 3-6, 2020](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/4-27-Release-Notes-August-3-6)

> **TRY_TO_DATE(), TRY_TO_TIME(), and TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP() Functions: Support Added for Optional Format Specifier**
>
> With this release, the TRY_TO_DATE(), TRY_TO_TIME(), and the TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP() family of functions support an optional format specifier, similar to the corresponding TO_DATE(), TO_TIME(), and TO_TIMESTAMP() functions.

---

**[TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html)**

> A special version of TO_DATE , DATE that performs the same operation (i.e. converts an input expression to a date), but with error-handling support (i.e. if the conversion cannot be performed, it returns a NULL value instead of raising an error).
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> TRY_TO_DATE( <string_expr> [, <format> ] )
> ```