# Convert Integer to Date in Snowflake using Error Handling

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where integer value should be converted to date type in Snowflake.Initially I used following query to get the desired result:

SELECT TO_DATE(TO_varchar(19000000+1200034),'YYYYMMDD')
2019-07-09

Now when I  used same query for the input - "20200034", I am getting following error:

select TO_DATE(TO_varchar(19000000+1200034),'YYYYMMDD')

Can't parse '20200034' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'

"20200034" is actually coming from  one of the columns in snowflake table. To resolve this issue I tried using "TRY_TO_DATE" function, but  output of "TRY_TO_DATE" function is giving incorrect result. Please find details below:

select TRY_TO_DATE(TO_varchar(19000000+1200034))

1970-08-22

As per Snowflake documentation, error handling function does not support   optional format argument supported by TO_DATE , DATE.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html

Comment: [TRY_TO_DATE with pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542450/try-to-date-with-pattern) - now it supports `TRY_TO_DATE(...., <pattern>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DATE_INPUT_FORMAT for the session before calling the TRY_TO_DATE function.

Comment: My main objective is to return default date value if input value is not parse able. I am trying to fix this issue using coalesce function.For example  COALESCE(TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(19000000 + <column_name>),'YYYYMMDD'),'2019-01-30') . Can this scenario be handled by setting DATE_INPUT_FORMAT?

Comment: alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT ='YYYYMMDD'; 

select TRY_TO_DATE(TO_varchar(19000000+1200034) );
 
select TRY_TO_DATE(TO_varchar(19000000+1201029) );

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you contact Snowflake support and ask them to enable try_to_date with format string - it's available but needs to be enabled manually.

However you have to be aware that TRY_TO_DATE on '20200034' will be resolved to NULL.

Comment: I want to handle this scenario using coalesce operation, since this function needs to applied on column values of snowflake table. For e.x COALESCE(TRY_TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(19000000 + <column_name>),'YYYYMMDD'),'2019-01-30')

Comment: that would totally work - and I'd still say contact support or set the DATE_INPUT_FORMAT in session as Mike told you - this will change the expected input format and the TRY_TO_DATE will parse according to that desired format (however that will also screw all the "default" formatted dates)